# Retrieve page URL params or page URL in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a page which has URL structure :
 http://www.abc.com/xyz?parama=1&paramb=2

- Is is possible to create a generic method for getting the values of any additional params the URL maybe (parama=1&paramb=2)
- Is is possible to get the URL of the page in XSL similar to javascript's location.href ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is is possible to get the URL of the page in XSL similar to javascript's location.href ?

**Not exactly in the same way, but yes, the query string can be passed as a parameter**.

> Is is possible to create a generic
>   method for getting the values of any
>   additional params the URL maybe
>   (parama=1&paramb=2)

**Yes, one can perform tokenization (with the** `tokenize()` **function in XSLT 2.0 or in XSLT 1.0 using the** `str-split-to-words` **template of [**FXSL 1.x](http://fxsl.sf.net)** or a self-written recursive tokenization template.)

**XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
>

   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
     <xsl:param name="pQString" select=
     "'?parama=1&amp;paramb=2&amp;anyParamName=AnyValue'"
     />


    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
      <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pQString"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters"
                  select="'?&amp;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*
     "/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when the above transformation is applied on any XML document (will not be used), the wanted result is produced**:

```
parama=1
paramb=2
anyParamName=AnyValue
```

**Do note** *the use of the FXSL 1.x `str-split-to-words` template and the use of the EXSLT `ext:node-set()` extension function*.

**XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pQString" as="xs:string" select=
 "'?parama=1&amp;paramb=2&amp;anyParamName=AnyValue'"
 />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of separator="&#xA;" select=
  "tokenize($pQString, '\?|&amp;')
  "/>
</xsl:template>
```

**When the above XSLT 2.0 transformation is performed, it produces the correct result**:

```
parama=1
paramb=2
anyParamName=AnyValue
```

Comment: The paramas for the URL are being passed dynamically to the URL. How can I read the dynamic params and to parse them as you noted above ?

Comment: THe ways to pass a global parameter to an XSLT stylesheet are implementation-dependent and are described as part of each implementation of XSLT. For example, in .NET a global parameter is specified using the AddParam() method of the XsltArgumentList class.

Using MSXML, it is necessary to use the AddParameter() object of the IXSLProcessor class. 

Yet in other systems the way to specify and pass a global parameter to an XSLT stylesheet will be different.

Once the global parameter is passed to the stylesheet, then the code in my answer will parse it as shown.

Answer (score 2):

This might be possible using [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/), or registering a function callback with your particular xslt processor, but not with plain old XSLT, at least not to my knowledge. With plain XSLT, if it isn't in the XML, then it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If it is client side, there isn't any way of doing this. Unfortunately, xsl is very limited in the browser. I'm afraid you will need to move the functionality to the webapp or to javascript.

If the transform is server side, there might be something you can do.

Comment: @Iris, I'm afraid I can't, I've only done browser side xslt. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I workaround this by using javascript in mi XSLT file. take a look.

on The XML I have a tag element named tag! yes, very original...

```
<tag url="http://www.demo.net/share.php?u=param1 />
```

Mi Sample transform

```
<div class="HelloDiv">
        <xsl:for-each select="tag">
          <a href="{@url}">
            This is my custom URL
          </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Now inside the template of the transform, in going to load my custom value in Param1
in this case i'm going to use the document.title.. by using a jquery function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('div.HelloDiv a').each(function(){
          var parameter = jQuery(this).attr('href');
          parameter = currentUrl.replace('param1',escape(document.title));
          jQuery(this).attr('href',parameter);
        })
      });
  </script>
```