# save query string into a variable

Tags: xslt

I want to save the a query string in to a variable in xslt.

How can I get this done?

```
www.mydomain.com/products/product.aspx?query="prod-+og+skipr"&searchField=Category&at=privat
```

My Xslt

```
<xsl:if test="$isloggedin != 'true'">
    <ul class="tax-switch">
        <li class="private-btn">
            <xsl:if test="library:RequestQueryString('at') = 'privat'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>private-btn active</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if> <a href="?at=privat" at="privat">Privat</a>
        </li>
        <li class="business-btn">
            <xsl:if test="library:RequestQueryString('at') = 'business'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>business-btn active</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if> <a href="?at=business" at="business">business</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

here a href only contain ?at=business but  I need the entire querystring attached before ?at

Comment: Please provide the xslt & xml you have so far

Comment: @Bigood hav any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633562/xslt-passing-url-querystring-as-a-parameter

Comment: What platform are you using to execute the XSLT? XSLT does not have a standard operation for retrieving query strings.