# Can I get the url of current page from xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Is is possible to get the URL of the page in XSL similar to javascript's location.href ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve page URL params or page URL in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812912/retrieve-page-url-params-or-page-url-in-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you have access to all XPath 2.0 functions https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/ and there you will find https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-document-uri e.g `document-uri(/)` and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-base-uri. Whether that helps to "get the URL of the page" I am not sure because I am not sure what you consider "the page". An XSLT document processes various input documents and you can find the URI of the currently processed one using `document-uri(/)`.